# Doing document.getElementsByName inside an array

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Can I really do this?

```
   $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: ajax_url,
    data: {'action': 'woocustom_change_orderstatus', 'order_id': document.getElementsByName("order-number")[0].value},
    success: function(response){
        alert("Order data successfully fetched.");                      
    }
});
```

I could declare a variable first. Just checking if it's really possible, since I'm not a programmer.

Comment: Trying it out would tell you immediately if it were possible or not

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but it is better to use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get the first element with a given name instead of finding all of them just to use the first one.

```js
document.querySelector("[name=order-number]").value
```

Comment: Given named elements are indexed (otherwise there wouldn't be a `getElementsByName()` function), I'm not sure it's that much more performant

Comment: @Phil True, but there's no need for creating a NodeList to get only one element. (Note that [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) also exists.)

Comment: Running some tests on https://jsbench.me/, the two approaches are reasonably equivalent.